# How to use setTimeout to make a list item wait for some time to restore its original color after a click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list items, clicking a list item should turn it red, i want every clicked item to wait for 3000ms to restore its black color again, this is my code

my trial is to use `setTimeout` in `useEffect` and setting all `red` fields to false but this didn't work, especially i need to make every red item to wait 3000ms from turning red to turn black again

The first item to click turn to black after 3000ms correctly, but after that items going black faster!!

```
  const App = () => {
        const items = [
            {
                name: 'mark',
                id: 1,
                red: false
            },
            {
                name: 'peter',
                id: 2,
                red: false
            },
            {
                name: 'john',
                id: 3,
                red: false
            }
        ]

        const [names, setNames] = useState(items);

        const turnItemRed= (id) => {
            setNames(
                names.map(i =>  i.id === id ? {...i, red: true} : i))
        }

     // this doesn't work
     useEffect(() => {
         setTimeout(() => {
             setNames( prev => prev.map( i => ({...i, red: false})))
         }, 3000)
     })

        return (
            <div class="items-cont">
                <ul class="items">
                    {
                        names.map(i => {
                            return (
                                <Item
                                    item={i}
                                    turnItemRed={turnItemRed}
                                />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Item = ({ item, ...props }) => {
        const { turnItemRed } = props;
        return (
            <li
                className={`${item.red ? 'red' : ''}`}
                onClick={() => {
                    turnItemRed(item.id)
                }}
            >
                {item.name}
            </li>
        )
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**CSS**:

```
.red {
     color: red
  }
```

Comment: *this didn't work* <-- What did happen? Did you get an error? Also, please post the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: css is simple, just a red class that turn the color to red, i have no console errors, it just doesn't work as i need

Comment: Please add the relevant CSS and HTML to your question so that we can see what your code does and more easily provide a working answer.

Comment: Seems like you put `3000` at the wrong place, it should be for `setTimeout` not `setNames`

Comment: this is react, no html, all elements are classes composed to be added finally to the root in the body, i will add the red class..thank you for trying to help

Comment: @thammada thank you that happened while writing the question here, i am trting to simplify the problem

Comment: You can just put `setTimeout` in `turnItemRed `. But why not put the state logic in `Item` component?

Comment: because it is a stateless component, i am used to write all my state logic in parent component

@thammada

Comment: > after that items going black faster!! My guess is that with setTimeout you'd need to create a new setTimeout, and you defined it in a way in which react might call the same setTimeout handler...

Comment: @octohedron i can't understand! why i need a new setTimeout and how to use it?

Comment: Same kind of reason why calling setTimeout on a loop doesn't run the setTimeout in sequence, so crate a new setTimeout for each call, for example on the onClick, but can't guarantee it's going to work

Comment: @octohedron yes you are completely right, and i know setting all red fields to false is a totally wrong idea, but my mind can't generate better than this, i know setTimeout fior each one would be right but i have no idea how to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code basically set all item back to original color at once.
Try the following code:
Note: This is simple way but the color when you can see it `red` then turn back to original color is not guarantee 3000 ms, because it take abit time to re-render component to show red

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const items = [
      {
          name: 'mark',
          id: 1,
          red: false
      },
      {
          name: 'peter',
          id: 2,
          red: false
      },
      {
          name: 'john',
          id: 3,
          red: false
      }
  ]

  const [names, setNames] = useState(items);

  const turnItemRed= (id) => {
      setNames(
          names.map(i =>  i.id === id ? {...i, red: true} : i))
      // move set timout here
      setTimeout(() => {
         setNames( prev => prev.map( i => i.id === id ? {...i, red: false} : i))
       }, 3000)
  }

  return (
      <div class="items-cont">
          <ul class="items">
              {
                  names.map(i => {
                      return (
                          <Item
                              item={i}
                              turnItemRed={turnItemRed}
                          />
                      )
                  })
              }
          </ul>
      </div>
  )
}

const Item = ({ item, ...props }) => {
  const { turnItemRed } = props;
  return (
      <li
          className={`${item.red ? 'red' : ''}`}
          onClick={() => {
              turnItemRed(item.id)
          }}
      >
          {item.name}
      </li>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Thank you but still the same problem exist, some items turn black very fast after turning red

Comment: @CodeEagle Sorry my bad. I forgot to remove `useEffect` part. Please check the updated code

Comment: thank you it works now :)..you still need to change ```red:true``` to ```red: false```  :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `useEffect` is running every 3 seconds, which means your component is re-rendering every 3 seconds with no UI actual updates.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setNames( prev => prev.map( i => ({...i, red: false})))
  }, 3000)
})
```

You need to change your `useEffect` to run only when `names` changes. Also make sure it runs only if some name has `red` property set to `true.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (names.some(item => item.red)) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNames(prev => prev.map(i => ({ ...i, red: false })));
    }, 3000);
  }
}, [names]);
```

Comment: Thank you but this generated the same problem!

Comment: I know, I figured it out in the comments later but you should describe the problem in description though. So, you want every name to be treated differently?

Comment: yes, they are not relevant to each others, once one get red, it should take 3 seconds to turn black, sorry if i couldn't describe my problem well